# Extract data between two words using sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, redhat

I have a log file and I am trying to extract data between 2 words of that log file.

```
username=#$^@$^&@#@%^&==&employeeid
```

There is data before and after these words but I am only interested in the data between them. Thus the expected output is (just the value between the `username=` and `&employeeid`

```
#$^@$^&@#@%^&==
```

I want to grep the file first and then search using `sed` in that file. Something like below. This is not working for me exactly..

```
grep "e553bb57-b94b-cb0f-f4ba-eb9a02ab0050" /path/abc/logfile.txt | sed -n '/username=/{s/.*username=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}'
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Er.. Isn't the sed command the OP has given be considered code?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
echo 'username=#$^@$^&@#@%^&==&employeeid' | sed 's/username=\(.*\)==&employeeid/\1/'
```

The output is

```
#$^@$^&@#@%^&
```

The matched part would be in `\1`.